# Maven 2 build Java web services? Help

Tags: java, web-services, maven-2, jax-ws

Has anyone built Java web services using Maven-2.  I've read about the jax-ws plugin, but I haven't found any clear documentation or examples on how to use it.

I tried building a few following instructions of some bloggers, but most instructions seem old or incomplete.

Does anyone have any advice on using Maven to build Java web service, or a link to a clean tutorial.

I'm using Maven 2.2.1, and Java 1.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of these :

http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_jax_ws_with_maven
http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html
https://jax-ws-commons.dev.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks dude, I used http://blogs.sun.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_jax_ws_with_maven - Which I had stumbled acorss before.  I had trouble deploying tomcat, was get a noSuchMethod exception.  When I upgraded jaxws-rt versions to 2.2.0.2 then everything worked like a charm.